# Writing data to the end of the running exe file

Tags: c++, process, c++17, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

I need to write a program that would add data to the end of its exe file. Either during execution or after. And I ran out of ideas on how to do it.

I tried to create and run copies of the program, but it didn't really help. I also tried to create zombie processes, but windows doesn't skip them.

Comment: You wont be able to modify the executable that is running as it will have a write access block until execution has finished. However you would easily be able to modify the exe thats not running, For example running App1.exe could modify the file App2.exe

Comment: @user20716902 "You wont be able to modify the executable that is running" - that depends on your OS. Not true or false in general. On Linux (and most other UNIX based systems) it's perfectly possible - on Windows, not so much.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The OP states **Windows**

Comment: Why do you need to do it? There's almost certainly a better approach. If you have to do it, creating a copy of the EXE and modifying that instead is probably the way to go.